# App crashes when table cell is tapped

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am using the [LeveyPopListView](https://github.com/levey/LeveyPopListView).
Inside the LeveyPopList View is a table containing jobs in a specific company. All is fine until I tap a job in the pop up list view and I've checked everything. 
Here's my code:

```
NSArray* ar_filter=(NSArray*)[self.FilterDictionary objectForKey:@"sub_slots"];
NSInteger numberOfJobs = [[[[[self.FilterDictionary objectForKey:@"sub_slots"] valueForKey:@"company_group"] valueForKey:@"job_count"] objectAtIndex:[self.jobsTableView indexPathForSelectedRow].row] intValue];
NSLog(@"NUMBER OF JOBS: %ld", (long)numberOfJobs);
NSLog(@"ARRAY FILTER: %@", ar_filter);

//MARK: for consolidated view
if([[ar_filter objectAtIndex:[self.jobsTableView indexPathForSelectedRow].row] objectForKey:@"company_group"])
{
    if(numberOfJobs > 1)
    {
        NSString *company_id = [[[[self.FilterDictionary objectForKey:@"sub_slots"] valueForKey:@"company_group"] valueForKey:@"company_id"] objectAtIndex:[self.jobsTableView indexPathForSelectedRow].row];
        NSString *company_name = [[[[self.FilterDictionary objectForKey:@"sub_slots"] valueForKey:@"company_group"] valueForKey:@"company_name"] objectAtIndex:[self.jobsTableView indexPathForSelectedRow].row];
        NSDictionary *specificCompany = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:company_id,@"company_id", nil];

        if(specificCompany.count>0)
        {
            NSError *error;
            NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:specificCompany
                                                               options:0
                                                                 error:&error];

            if (! jsonData)
            {
                NSLog(@"Got an error: %@", error);
            }
            else
            {
                strJsonStringFilter = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
            }
        }

        allJobsDictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:[network getData:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"get_all_job_offers?pt_id=%@&filter=%@",[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"pt_id"], strJsonStringFilter]] options:kNilOptions error:nil];
        //this contains the jobs that are given by allJobsDictionary
        jobsToDisplay=(NSArray*)[allJobsDictionary objectForKey:@"sub_slots"];
        //call LeveyPopListView
        LeveyPopListView *lplv = [[LeveyPopListView alloc] initWithTitle:company_name options:jobsToDisplay handler:^(NSInteger anIndex)
        {
        }];

        lplv.delegate = self;
        [lplv showInView:self.view animated:YES];
        strJsonStringFilter = @"";
    }
}

- (void)leveyPopListView:(LeveyPopListView *)popListView didSelectedIndex:(NSInteger)anIndex {
    NSDictionary *job = (NSDictionary*)[jobsToDisplay objectAtIndex:anIndex];

    // Pass data and transit to detail job view controller
    [self.parentViewController performSelector:@selector(showJobDetailWith:) withObject:job];
}

-(void)showJobDetailWith:(NSDictionary *)dictionary {
    // Pass data to global variable for prepareForSegue method
    mapPinSelectedDictionary = dictionary;

    UIStoryboard  *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];

    MTJobDetailTableViewController *smsController=[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MTJobDetailTableViewController"];

    [smsController setJobDetailDict:mapPinSelectedDictionary];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:smsController animated:YES];
}
```

from **LeveyPopListVIew.m**

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];

    // tell the delegate the selection
    if ([_delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(leveyPopListView:didSelectedIndex:)])
        [_delegate leveyPopListView:self didSelectedIndex:[indexPath row]];

    if (_handlerBlock)
        _handlerBlock(indexPath.row);

    // dismiss self
    [self fadeOut];
}
```

The app crashes when this line of code:

```
[self.parentViewController performSelector:@selector(showJobDetailWith:) withObject:job];
```

is called. Can anyone help me this. Thank you.

Comment: take any one method bro , use either did select index or showJobDetailWith method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
- (void)leveyPopListView:(LeveyPopListView *)popListView didSelectedIndex:(NSInteger)anIndex {
NSDictionary *job = (NSDictionary*)[jobsToDisplay objectAtIndex:anIndex];

// Pass data and transit to detail job view controller
UIStoryboard  *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];

MTJobDetailTableViewController *smsController=[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MTJobDetailTableViewController"];

[smsController setJobDetailDict: job];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:smsController animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: hey man..worked like a charm! Thank you very much.. :)
ill accept this as an answer after 5mins. Again. thank you very much..

Comment: tanx a lot my friend , have a nice day ,

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik I am using this leveyPopListView. the delegate method is not called when clicking a cell.                                                     func leveyPopListView(popListView: LeveyPopListView!, didSelectedIndex anIndex: Int)

Comment: @AbiramiBala - are you set the leveyPopListView.delegate =self in your current class at the same time check once leveyPopListViewdelegate added in your class

Comment: Yes Tried it but it shows an error like, instance member 'delegate' cannot be used on type 'LeveyPopListView'. So Im unable to set it.